# How can I decrypt a file encrypted in Perl using Crypt::CBC (Blowfish) in C?

Tags: c++, perl, encryption, blowfish

I have a small encryption tool in Perl which uses the [Crypt::CBC](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt::CBC) and Blowfish to encrypt files.

I want to write the decryption algorithm in C or C++ ... Please somebody help me in doing this.

Comment: You are first going to have to decide whether you are going do it in C or C++.

Answer (score 8):

Blowfish source code is available [here](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html). Note that since blowfish is a symmetric encryption system, encryption and decryption are the same operation.

Answer (score 2):

You could always [embed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) Perl in your C program...

(Update: at least one person seems to think that's a bad idea; it's really not that hard to do, and saves the hassle of worrying whether the Perl implementation of blowfish exactly matches whatever library you find to do it in C.)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is](http://andreyvitdev.blogspot.com/2005/10/crypto-usage-sample.html) a sample using [CryptoPP](http://www.cryptopp.com/) one of the greatest crypto libraries.